# Selecting the right PMDC motor and battery

Tags: dc-motor, input, efficiency, alternator

I'm looking at generating electrical energy from a mechanical input being used to rotate the shaft of a Permanent magnet DC motor. However, i'm a bit stuck with selecting the right motor and battery to store the energy in(and everything else needed between)

My average mechanical input to the motor will have a power of approximately 200W, and the shaft RPM would be in the range of 500-1500. However, the RPM will be prone to fluctuation within this range (It's an ergometer so RPM and Torque will vary throughout each individual stroke)

I plan to store the produced electrical power in a battery. However, i'm not very clued up at all with the electronics side of things.

My first question is: Is it best to use a Permanent magnet DC motor as a generator, or an Alternator? I'm not quite clear which is best in this situation and why. Since I will be storing the energy in a battery, i have been going on the assumption that a DC motor is best?

Secondly: What other components are needed in the circuit between the motor and the battery? And what kind of efficiency can i expect from each component (Very approximate?)? IE if i put 200W in, how much can i expect to actually reach the battery?

Finally: Is it possible to charge a battery with an unstable voltage? or would this present problems and some method of controlling the voltage would be needed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is: Is it best to use a Permanent magnet DC motor as
>   a generator, or an Alternator?

An automotive alternator is probably more power fuel than you need and more complex to use that you would like.

A permanent-magnet DC motor with a commutator would probably be ok. You may also want to consider a 3-phase brushless DC motor. That is essentially the same as a permanent-magnet synchronous motor. It would generate AC, but it would be quite efficient and easy to rectify to DC.

> What other components are needed in the circuit between the motor and the battery?

You need a voltage converter to convert the variable DC from the generator to the battery charging voltage. You also should have a charge controller that could be combined with the voltage converter.

> And what kind of efficiency can i expect from each component

Generator: 75 - 90+%

Rectifier, converter, charge controller: 80 - 90+% combined

Mechanical system: 85 - 97%

The system efficiency curve vs. speed starts at zero speed zero efficiency, then rises, rapidly at first, to maximum efficiency at or near maximum speed.

> Is it possible to charge a battery with an unstable voltage?

Some variation is ok, but you will need a voltage converter and charge controller to get the voltage into acceptable limits and control the current.